# Sort Prompt Values in Descending order in SAS Enterprise Guide 5.1

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I have a prompt in a SAS Enterprise Guide 5.1 project that lets the user select years between 1910-2014. The values are currently ordered ascending. Is there a simple way to order descending so I don't have to use the "Move Down" button 100 times?

Comment: How are the data values loaded into the prompt?  Via a data source/metadata source, or are they effectively hand-entered?

Comment: They are loaded from a csv file, which is in descending order.

Comment: So it's a "static list" populated through "Get Values"?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: 'get Values' is on the 'Filter ' tab, not 'Sort' tab. You can 'sort' by the name of the column that stores these 'years' and check the descending radio button.